# Looking for a fantasy anime about a guy whose arm was slowly turning black

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember watching the anime when I was a kid. It was about a blonde guy who had an arm that was slowly turning black. He was kind of hot blooded. There was a girl with him who had pink hair and was a mage or something. I think he fights some guy but his arm starts acting up. At one point he falls off a cliff.

I've been looking for this anime for a long time but have had no luck -__-

Comment: When were you "a kid"?  5 years ago?  15 years?  30?

Comment: Also, what language were you watching this in?  Was it dubbed or subbed?  Was it a fansub or an official translation?  Was it on TV or VHS/DVD?

Comment: *Princess Mononoke* is the first thing that leaps to mind, except every single hair color is wrong.  I'm guessing those tropes have been done a lot.